# Xcode Source control commit winow showing no files

Tags: xcode, git

I created a new project and try to commit it from source control tab. But the commit widow does not show any files.

[image: Commit screen]

Comment: Can you open terminal, change the current directory to the root of the project, and run `git status`? Please update the question with its output?

Comment: Are there any files in the project navigator with M next to them? When you create a new project, there is not anything to commit. You have to edit files or add files to the project to have anything to commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that your project is not being tracked by git. To enable tracking, you need to open the project directory in command prompt and run following command -

```
git init
```

This will initialise git in your project repo and start tracking your files.

Comment: Ya, I tried that before and it creates a .git folder. Then I try the same but still it showing empty.